# How to work with multiple windows in Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I want to have 2 tkinter Windows. On the main Window there should be a button which opens a new window and closes the original one. Below you can see my minimal Code example.

So far the first window opens but as soon as I push the button both windows just close.

- Please tell me what my specific error is int this code?
- Is there a way to emprove my code?(general tips)?

.

```
def Func_Show_Rep(self):
         #destroy main window
         Cockpit_Win.quit()
         Cockpit_Win.destroy()

         # Open new Window
         ReportSelection_Win = Toplevel()  

         ReportSelection_Win = Tk()


#create the main window
Cockpit_Win = Tk()

Btt_Show_Rep = Button(Cockpit_Win, text="Reports", width=35)
Btt_Show_Rep.bind("<Button-1>",Func_Show_Rep)#Button click starts function
Btt_Show_Rep.grid(column=1, row=2, padx=10, pady=7, sticky=E)

#Make the windows stay (loop)      
Cockpit_Win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have a `TopLevel` window when the `root` window is destroyed with Tkinter. The `TopLevel` window is built on top of the `root` window.

If you want to destroy (effectively **hide**) the `Cockpit_Win` window, use the following:

```
Cockpit_Win.withdraw()
```

When you want to make it visible again, use:

```
Cockpit_Win.deiconify()
```

The entire code looks like this:

```
def Func_Show_Rep(self):  
         # Open new Window
         ReportSelection_Win = Toplevel()  

         #ReportSelection_Win = Tk() # This is the same as the previous statement
         #destroy (effectively hide) main window
         Cockpit_Win.withdraw()


#create the main window
Cockpit_Win = Tk()

Btt_Show_Rep = Button(Cockpit_Win, text="Reports", width=35)
Btt_Show_Rep.bind("<Button-1>",Func_Show_Rep)#Button click starts function
Btt_Show_Rep.grid(column=1, row=2, padx=10, pady=7, sticky=E)

#Make the windows stay (loop)      
Cockpit_Win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks, works mainly great but, the main window reloads (so vanishes briefly and reappears) and is empty (so no widgets on it). the second window would work at this point.

Comment: To avoid this, initialize the `TopLevel` window `ReportSelection_Win` above the `withdraw` statement. I edited the answer to reflect this

Comment: Unfortunatley i still get the same error. This is my current code:
`def Func_Show_Rep(self):
ReportSelection_Win = Toplevel()
Cockpit_Win.withdraw()` with indents ^^

Comment: It works well for me. However, you can also add `ReportSelection_Win.lift()` and/or `ReportSelection_Win.focus_force()` to focus in on your `TopLevel` window